# Как автоматически закрыть приложение когда из Shared Preferences будет удалено значение

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

У меня в приложении есть `Id` пользователя хранится в `Shared Preferences`, я его использую в разных `Activitу`,`Fragment` и он мне нужен постоянно.

Но в случае если `Shared Preferences` или некоторые значения из  них будут удалены - я хочу об этом узнать и завершить работу приложения.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Мониторить значения? Создать broadcast?

Comment: А как этот бродкаст прикрутить к Shared Preferences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html):

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new haredPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // здесь можете закрыть приложение
    }
};
```